# Can the body of any organism on Earth live without impairment both in vacuum, and within Earth's atmosphere?

Tags: physiology, speculative, extremophiles

I know from reading that a human in vacuum needs a space-suit to survive.

Is the body of any organism on Earth capable of living equally in vacuum, and on/below Earth's surface within the atmosphere?

Comment: I think this is more of a physics question than biology.

Comment: Any body?  As in you're looking for an organism that is capable of surviving in a vacuum and with an atmosphere or you're looking for [Chuck Norris](http://www.chucknorrisfacts.com/)?  Assuming not the latter , google suggests [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deinococcus_radiodurans) but it's an unreferenced Wiki point :/

Comment: On *what*'s surface?

Comment: Yeah, what do you mean by 'on its surface'?

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but people did because your question in its original formulation made no sense.

Comment: I'd like to add that most of the answers here have the organisms in hibernated forms.  I think there is a fungus that was growing in the space station, but I'm not sure anything on earth is functional in the vacuum of space, only hibernating... anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remarkably, [Tardigrades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade) are multi-cellular animals which can [survive the vacuum of space](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn14690-water-bears-are-first-animal-to-survive-space-vacuum.html).

Comment: I even think NASA sent a few of them up to space, brought them back to earth and awakened them...

Comment: "Tardigrades" are basically the answer to every biology question which begins with "can any animal...", aren't they?

Comment: And they're so cute too! http://cdn.zmescience.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/tardigrades-electronmiscroppe.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Noah's answer, some lichens can survive the vacuum of space too. In an experiment led by Leopoldo Sancho from the Complutense University of Madrid, two species of lichen - *Rhizocarpon geographicum* and *Xanthoria elegans* - were sealed in a capsule and launched on a Russian Soyuz rocket on 31 May 2005. The [lichens](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn8297-hardy-lichen-shown-to-survive-in-space.html) were in perfect condition when observed after the return to earth.