# Is it possible to have life in vacuum?

Tags: physiology, speculative, extremophiles

I just got struck by curiosity now: Intuition says no, but I've never had confirmation of it.

Comment: Define life. You can probably get viral spores that can survive and even some extremophile bacteria but in a dormant state. Would you consider something that is not interacting with its environment in any way at the moment alive?

Comment: See very similar question and answers here: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2700/can-the-body-of-any-organism-on-earth-live-without-impairment-both-in-vacuum-an/2703#2703

Comment: nobody has had confirmation of this - with the possible exception of the tardigrade in space experiment and those like it in the ISS/space shuttle.

Comment: You could build robots that feed on debris, like man made satellites, that satisfy common definitions of life (e.g. Reproduce, have a metabolism etc). In general life as we know it does not do well in space because it is very cold, and not much chemically is going on to support metabolic processes. The lack of food, water and the vacuum make it rough as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @terdon comments, dormant organisms can survive in vacuum. This includes lichens, bacteria, and even an animal: the ever-amazing and adorable tardigrade ([Jönnson et al 2008](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cub.2008.06.048)). In 2006, tardigrades survived exposure to the vacuum of outer space with **no appreciable difference in mortality** compared to controls.

[image: CC by-nc-ca by Goldstein lab - tardigrades]

Tardigrade *Hypsibius dujardini*, a different genus than the ones sent into space, but probably equally hardy. Photo by Bob Goldstein & Vicky Madden (CC by-nc-ca via [Goldstein lab - tardigrades on flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/waterbears/2851666759/)).

---

[Jönsson, K. I. et al (2008). Tardigrades survive exposure to space in low Earth orbit. Current Biology 18(17):R729–R731](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cub.2008.06.048)

Comment: Be able to survive it is quite different from living permanently in it...

Comment: I agree! Which is why I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not. Or at least not in the form we know life. The reason is that water (which is essential for life) boils at low pressures at room temperature. This makes life impossible in the form we live it on earth.

Answer (score 1):

No, because some kind of fluid (liquid or gas) is necessary to supply resources and carry away wastes. Bacterial spores, tardigrades, etc. are in a dormant state when in a vacuum.